# how to populate initial state of pinia store in a unit test

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vuejs3, vitest

I want to write a unit-tests for this a pinia store like :

```
export const useMyStore = defineStore("MyStore", () => {
  // private state in the store
  const myProp = ref<string[]>([])

  // a method to populate the state
  const fetch = async ()=>{
    myProp.value = await someHttpRequest()
  }

  // a private method on myProp
  const myPrivateMethod = (): void => {
     myProp.value.sort() // example method
     // please note the return type is void
  }

  // exported getter
  const getMyProp = computed(()=>{
    return [...myProp.value]
  })

  const publicMethod = () => {
    myPrivateMethod()
  }

  return {
    fetch,
    getMyProp,
    publicMethod
  }
}
```

**The Question**
How to **initiate** the store with some "test"-data in `myProp`, so that by calling "publicMethod" i can make sure from the results, that the "privateMethod" worked properly?

Please note that all my attempts gave me an empty list.

Any  hint is really appreciated

I tried to initiate the store as mentioned in [the documentation](https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/testing.html)

```
beforeEach(() => {
    setActivePinia(
      createTestingPinia({
        initialState: {
          myStoreName: {
            myProp: [...values]
          }
        }
      })
    )
})

it("should sort the list and get the sorted list back", async () => {
  const myStore = useMyStore()
  myStore.publicMethod()

  expect(store.getMyProp).toBe([
    // sorted list elements are here
  ])  

}
```

Another approach was:

```
const myPropPlugIn = ()=>{
  return {myProp: [...someValues]}
}
let pinia
beforeEach(() => {
  pinia = createPinia().use(myPropPlugIn)
  setActivePinia(pinia)
})

it("should sort the list and get the sorted list back", async () => {
  const myStore = useMyStore()
  myStore.publicMethod()

  expect(store.getMyProp).toBe([
    // sorted list elements are here
  ])  

}
```

with both approaches I was not able to get the `myProp` pre-initiated

Comment: It failed because myProp is not a part of public state, it's just local variable inside store setup function. What's the purpose of getMyProp? You could use myProp instead

Comment: You don't need to populate the initial value of the store in order to test the sorting. Mock fetch and pass some unsorted data and test that it is sorted in the computed.